# pyodbc.ProgrammingError '42000', [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot find data type 'TEXT'. (104220) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse

I am creating the necessary connections followed by creating a dataframe which I want to send to Azure SQL Database.
I am getting stuck at the last part.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#The last line of code gives me the programming error as stated in the question
#Please, please try to help me with this , I will be eternally grateful

#Creating connections

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, select
from six.moves import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(r'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL 
Server};Server=tcp:abcd.sql.azuresynapse.net,1433;Database=xxx;Uid=yyy;Pwd= 
{zzz};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=yes;Connection Timeout=30;')
conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params)
engine = create_engine(conn_str,connect_args={'autocommit': True})
engine.connect() 
 

#Create dataframe

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','Subject','Marks','GPA'])
df['Name']=['A','B','C','D','E']
df['Subject']=['IUDI','KDBJSCJ','SJIJSABCIBSA','DCOSANNOA','SDOISD']
df['Marks']=[659 for i in range(0,5)]
df['GPA']=[8.0 for i in range(0,5)]
 
#Export Dataframe to sql (Problem code)
df.to_sql(name='demo_table',con=engine,index=False)
```

Comment: Hi @bkghosh, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error creating / replacing a table on Azure synapse until I manually specified `dtypes` as sqlalchemy column types (see pandas  [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import NVARCHAR, INTEGER, FLOAT
col_types = {"Name": NVARCHAR(1),
             "Subject": NVARCHAR(12),
             "Marks": INTEGER,
             "GPA": FLOAT}
df.to_sql(name="demo_table", con=engine, dtype=col_types, if_exists="replace")
```

It is not the first time Azure Synapse turns out to have poorer support than plain SQL Server. I imagine it simply has problems inferring the data type.