Incorrect syntax near 'CAST' when using pandas.to_sql
I'm trying to write some code to update an sql table from the values in a pandas dataframe.  The code I'm using to do this is:
df.to_sql(name='streamlit_test', con=engine, schema='dbo', if_exists='replace', index=False)

Using an sqlalchemy engine. However, I'm getting the error:
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
[SQL: SELECT cast(com.value as nvarchar(max)) FROM fn_listextendedproperty('MS_Description', 'schema', CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)), 'table', CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)), NULL, NULL ) as com; ]
[parameters: ('dbo', 'streamlit_test')]

I thought it might be something to do with data types, so I've tried changing the dtypes of my dataframe to match the corresponding data types in the table I'm trying to write to (using this lookup: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/python/python-libraries-and-data-types?view=sql-server-ver16) but I'm still getting the same error.  I haven't managed to find anyone else with a similar problem through googling, so any help/pointers is greatly appreciated!
Edit
I've tried using:
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql import BIGINT, FLOAT, TEXT, BIT
df.to_sql(name='streamlit_test', con=engine, schema='dbo',
          if_exists='replace', index=False,
          dtype={'col1':BIGINT, 'col2':FLOAT, 'col3':TEXT,
                            'Tickbox':BIT, 'Comment':TEXT})

so that the dtypes match what they are in the created table, but I still get the same error.  For more context, to_sql works fine and saves the dataframe to a table if the table doesn't already exist, and if I change if_exists='replace' to if_exists='append', that also works, but when trying to replace the data in the existing table, I get the 42000 error.
My MSSMS version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3-GDR) (KB4057113) - 10.50.6560.0 (X64)   Dec 28 2017 15:03:48   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68006708/pyodbc-programmingerror-42000-microsoftodbc-driver-17-for-sql-serversql

Are you able to connect directly from a query tool like SSMS, Azure Data Studio, DBeaver, etc.? If so, what does select @@version return?

can you try this something like this
df.to_sql(name='streamlit_test', con=engine, schema='dbo', if_exists='replace', index=False,
dtype={'column1': String, 'column2': Integer})

@JonSG  I've tried that method and am still having the same error (see edits)

@samhita I've tried that method and am still having the same error (see edits)

@GordThompson I've edited my question to include this :)

For debugging purpose, are you able to check the query_history in database and check what exactly it is trying to run in database side ?

Hmm, I have been unable to reproduce the error on "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)". What do you get from select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = 'your_database_name' ?

@GordThompson returns an empty compatibility level column

Did you substitute your actual database name for 'your_database_name' ?

@GordThompson yes I did, it doesn't return anything,  I initially created the table using .to_sql with replace, but I don't seem to be able to further replace the data in it through pandas

Try pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.54 and see if that helps.

@GordThompson Now I can't read in anything, let alone write :( I'm using create_engine for my connection, and using read_sql gives an error AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'cursor' which I didn't have before I changed the sqlalchemy version

As for to_sql, I get an error of raise ValueError(f"{col} ({my_type}) not a string") ValueError: col1 (<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.INTEGER'>) not a string which is odd as col1 is an integer, and I'm specifying in to_sql that it should be an integer, so I don't know what it thinks it should be a string

With SQLAlchemy 1.4 you may also need an older version of pandas, perhaps pip install pandas==1.5.3

I'm getting some pip problems trying to install that version of pandas, I'll need to sort that out and get back to you

You could try pip install pandas==2.1.4. That seems to work for me with sqlalchemy 1.4.54.

@GordThompson sorry it's been a couple of days, but it worked using those versions!!! Thank you for your help, any idea what the issue was? If you want to write a solution I'll accept it :)

Microsoft SQL Server offers limited support for using databases that are compatible with earlier versions. For example, SQL Server 2008 creates databases with compatibility level 100 (SQL Server 2008) by default, but it also allows us to use databases that are compatible with
SQL Server 2005 - database compatibility level 90
SQL Server 2000 - database compatibility level 80
SQLAlchemy 2.0 added a feature to reflect table comments. That feature uses the query
SELECT cast(com.value as nvarchar(max))
FROM fn_listextendedproperty('MS_Description',
    'schema', CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)), 'table', CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)), NULL, NULL
) as com;

and that syntax is only supported for database compatibility level ≥ 90. Executing that same query on a database with compatibility level ≤ 80 results in

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

SQLAlchemy 1.4 is required to work with such old databases, e.g.,
pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.54 pandas==2.1.4

